# Distributing projects that reference NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a product which essentially is a developer kit - a set of .NET assemblies (compiled only) for specific purpose. The product installation also includes examples of the usage, which I distribute in form of Visual Studio projects, in source form. Some of these example reference additional NuGet packages (that are not used in the product itself). Specifically, it is the Rx-Main package (for Microsoft Reactive Extensions), but it can also be something else.

In my test, I have referenced this package from the example, acknowledged the license conditions, observed all the files (including package assemblies built for many platforms) it adds to the project structure, and then included them in my installation. This works, but has following problems:

1) I am not sure that it would be in line with license conditions to redistribute the package this way. As a minimum I would expect the end user be asked to re-acknowledge the package license conditions when he opens the project in Visual Studio, but it is not happening.

2) The package binary files are unnecessarily included within the installation, making it bigger. I can safely assume that the user has an Internet connection and can download the package. Therefore I would prefer to distribute just a "reference" to the package. Only when the user actually needs the example, he would download the references package(s).

I have tried to do this by removing the 'packages' directory from the project/installation, and only keeping the packages.config file (which seems to contain the package identification/reference). I hoped that when such project is opened in Visual Studio, the package will be detected as missing and re-downloaded etc. But it does not work - it simply complains about missing assemblies (those that should come from the referenced package), and makes no attempt to load the package.

The question is thus, how can I distribute Visual Studio projects (in source form) that reference NuGet packages, without actually distributing the packages themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely looking for [package restore feature](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) of NuGet.

Comment: Oh great, yes. It looks that I need the "automatic package restore" option. The reason I have not found out is that I intentionally have my examples in VS2012 and made the test in VS2012. It appears that VS2012 has an earlier version of NuGet that does not have this feature (or does not have in full, and certainly the part that is available is turned off by default). In VS2013 it is all enabled by default, and according to the MSDN link you provided, it should do precisely what I expect. I am accepting the answer although I have not yet tested it out...

Comment: @ZbynekZ I believe it should be enough to update NuGet extension. I have seen package restore feature available even in VS2010.

Comment: You are right, it depends on the NuGet version, not on the VS version. Updating the NuGet in VS2012 makes it work. This reveals one "hidden" requirement that I should have mentioned in the original question: I wanted it to work with "out of the box" installation. And, in VS2012 this is not the case. I understand that updating the NuGet extension and enabling the necessary options resolves the issue, but I would be much happier if it had worked without it. Anyway, I deem it resolved, because in VS2013 it works out of the box, and VS2012 is being phased out, I can just document it for VS2012.